# How to get the nonspatial tables in the TOC into a combobox in ArcMap?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#

I'm new in using Arcobject . i'd like to set dbf of ArcMap TOC to the Combobox Items. 
How can i set dbf files to items of combobox using C# programming and Arcobject ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'set dbf files to items of combobox'? Do you want to get a list of dbf files, or tables that are added in the Map?

Comment: yes . i want to get a list of dbf files or tables aht added in the ArcMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast from the Map Object to the [IStandaloneTableCollection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IStandaloneTableCollection_Interface/001200000qv4000000/) Interface.

You can get the number of standalone tables that this map contains using the StandaloneTableCount property, and then get the appropriate table using the [IStandaloneTableCollection.StandaloneTable](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/StandaloneTable_Property/001200000qv8000000/) Property

Comment: @wetland I'm glad to hear that.